# devise config.action_mailer.default_url_options not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, actionmailer, devise-confirmable

I have switched over to pow in order to use ssl in development and I want to switch the host configuration in development, however devise continues to send email prefixed with the localhost:3000 domain. Here is what I have in my config/environments/development.rb file:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'want_freight.dev' }
```

I have restarted my server and I have grepped my entire application looking for the offending use of localhost:3000 however my search turned up nothing outside of tmp and log files. Does anyone know why this would not be working??

Comment: I am also experiencing this issue.  It's odd because anything besides :host and :port does end up in the query string in actionmailer but the one thing I really need to default doesn't work.

Comment: Any chance you'll accept the answer? Were you able to try this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was actually related to the devise_async gem causing conflicts with the mailer, I was able to resolve the issue by removing the gem from my gemfile.

Answer (score 4):

I changed config.action_mailer.default_url_options to point to Pow's .dev URL, [restarted my computer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p85xwZ_OLX0), and, against all odds, it was working again.

Comment: the technical term is "power cycling"

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to have some success by adding :only_path => false to the default_url_options hash and using named urls, e.g. user_url( @user.id ) instead of link_to.

Answer (score 0):

No need to restart computer, just restart POW:

touch ~/.pow/restart.txt